# Is it possible to negate a group in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Let's say that we have this text:

```
2020-09-29
2020-09-30
2020-10-01
2020-10-02
2020-10-12
2020-10-16
2020-11-12
2020-11-23
2020-11-15
2020-12-01
2020-12-11
2020-12-30
```

I want to do something like this:
\d\d\d\d-(NOT10)-(30)

So i want to get all dates of any year, but not of the 10th month and it is important, that the day is 30.

I tried a lot to do this using negative lookahead asserations but i did not come up with any working regexes.

Comment: "NOT10" == `0[1-9]|1[12]`

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say you want to "get all dates of any year" (of which there are 365 or 366) except for one, October 30. But that has nothing to do with the string you show. Do you mean you wish to extract all dates from the string other than October 30? Some answers suggest you want all dates in the list where the day is 30 and the month is not October. Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [negative lookaheads](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):

```
\d\d\d\d-(?!10)\d\d-30
```

The Part `(?!10)` ensures that no `10` follows at the point where it is inserted into the regex. Notice that you still need to match the following digits afterwards, thus the `\d\d` part.

Generally speaking you can not (to my knowledge) negate a part that then also matches parts of the string. But with negative lookaheads you can simulate this as I did above. The generalized idea looks something like:

```
(?!<special-exclusion-pattern>)<general-inclusion-pattern>
```

Where the special-exclusion-pattern matches a subset of the general-inclusion-pattern. In the above case the general inclusion pattern is `\d\d` and the special exclusion pattern ins `10`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to do like that \d{4}-(?!10)-30 but i could not understand why it does not work! Thank you!

Comment: This matches all dates that fall on day 30 of every month other than month 10. How does that help the OP obtain all dates in the list but at most one?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
/20\d{2}-(?:0[1-9]|1[12])-30/
```

Explanation :

**20\d{2}** it will match 20XX

**(?:0[1-9]|1[12])** it will match 0X or 11, 12

**30** it will match 30

Demo :https://regex101.com/r/O2F1eV/1

Comment: `0\d` might be overly broad since the pattern will match `00`

Comment: I think it only need a simple regex,

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to simply convert the substring (if present) that matches `/^\d{4}-10-30$/` to an empty string, then split the resulting string on one or more newlines.

If your string were

```
2020-10-16
2020-10-30
2020-11-12
2020-11-23
```

and was held by the variable `str`, then in Ruby, for example,

```
str.sub(/^\d{4}-10-30$/,'')
  #=> "2020-10-16\n\n2020-11-12\n2020-11-23\n"
```

so

```
str.sub(/^\d{4}-10-30$/,'').split
  #=> ["2020-10-16", "2020-11-12", "2020-11-23"]
```

Whatever language you are using undoubtedly has similar methods.